# How can I use a gradient as background in a Bokeh chart?

Tags: python, plot, colors, bokeh

I am trying to create with Bokeh a chart similar to the dark style chart in Excel. It seems to be lighter in the center and then getting darker.

To set the color of the background in Bokeh, you can do the following, found in the relevant [Bokeh documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#background):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("background.html")

# create a new plot with a title
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.background_fill_color = "beige"
p.background_fill_alpha = 0.5

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)

show(p)
```

Also, in the [Bokeh documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#specifying-colors) mentions the ways you can specify color:

> Colors properties are used in many places in Bokeh, to specify the
>   colors to use for lines, fills or text. Color values can be provided
>   in any of the following ways:
>
> ```
> - any of the 147 named CSS colors, e.g 'green', 'indigo'
> - an RGB(A) hex value, e.g., '#FF0000', '#44444444'
> - a 3-tuple of integers (r,g,b) between 0 and 255
> - a 4-tuple of (r,g,b,a) where r, g, b are integers between 0 and 255 and a is a floating point value between 0 and 1
> ```

Based on the above it seems you can only set one color for the background.

Is there a way to set a gradient as the background color in a Bokeh chart ?

Comment: There are probably ways to do this "by hand" with `image` or `image_rgba` glyph methods, but there is currently (as of `0.11.1` release) not any way to specify a gradient directly as the background fill. This could be a reasonable feature, I'd encourage you to create an issue on the GH issue tracker to discuss it: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: I took your advice and opened an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh 0.13.0 this is not supported. Background fill color can only be a single color.

Answer (score 0):

As [@bigreddot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406693/bigreddot) mentioned, the available solution at the moment for creating a gradient background in bokeh is to do it manually. Your example becomes:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper
import numpy as np

output_file("background.html")

# create a new plot with a title
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_range=[0.8, 6], y_range=[1.8, 8.2])

# gradient background
x = np.linspace(1, 0, 256)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)

xArray, yArray = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plotArray = xArray + yArray

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette="Greys256", low=0, high=1)

p.image(image=[plotArray], color_mapper=color_mapper, dw=5.2, dh=6.5, x=[0.8], y=[1.8])

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)

show(p)
```

The output is the following:

[image: bokeh_plot_example]